# Best place/way to register and de register for contentObserver

Tags: java, android, contentobserver

I have an use case where I have to register for content observer in my android app.
I want to listen right from app start till my app is closed, but my application contains many activities, which is the best place to register and de-register for the observer?

If I do that in my base activity's onResume and onPause, registering and deregistering would happen frequently (as the activities also change during user actions), is there a better place to register and de register?

Thanks,
Rishi.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do things across multiple activities, use a Service.  Have each activity start the Service (if its already running that won't cause a second to start) and have it register.  If you need to access data from that observer, use the Binder to define an API and bind to the service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

There is a callback in the contentObserver which I want to leverage, there is no such data which I would like to get from the "service" if any.
However, how would creating a service help the problem?
I need something which starts observing right after the app start and stop after the app is killed.

Comment: A started Service exists until its stopped.  That means it continues to exist even if one Activity is stopped and another starts.  Its purpose is to do tasks that are needed no matter what Activity is running, or to do tasks whose results are needed by multiple Activities in your app.  You may also consider using JobScheduler to schedule a JobService for a content resolver.

Comment: I see,

on the JobScheduler part:
I can just have a static util to trigger the method (basically, a state less method) when ever I get a "onChange" callback from the content observer, What addition/advantage would JobScheduler add here?